# "ranked for" or "ranked by"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In a presentation I'm watching now there are phrases like "ranked for stability", "ranked for priority". It looks strange to me. I think it should be "ranked by". So which is correct?

Example: Requirements are ranked by priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranked **for** purpose **by** property.

> Ranked **for** server usage **by** stability.
>
> Ranked **for** sniper units **by** shooting range performance.
>
> Ranked **for** the awards **by** number of votes.

In that context, *ranked for priority, by stability* probably.